# Do high/low always refer to high/low pitch?

Tags: vocabulary

I understand we have loud/soft to describe the loudness of a sound. We also have high/low pitch sounds which are sometimes shortened to low/high sounds. Are there other ways to express the loudness and frequency of sound/voice?

Also, is it possible that native speakers use low and high instead of soft and loud?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If mean that someone spoke quietly or softly, we can instead say they spoke in a low voice, but we would not say they spoke in a 'high voice' to mean that they spoke loudly. That would mean they spoke in a high-pitched voice (e.g. a man trying to sound like a child).